# Bot looks for channel in one guild, not in all discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to send a message to a specific channel, and it works only in the server, where the channel is in. Do you have any idea how to fix it?
What I tried:
`message.guild.channels.cache.get("816714319172599828")`
The error I get:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`

Edit: My full code:

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: "feedback",
    description: "Send your feedback for the bot!",
    async execute(message, args) {

        const feedback = args.slice(0).join(" ");
        const no_feedback = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#993333")
        .setTitle("Feedback")
        .setDescription("An error has occured.")
        .addField("Error" , "You didn't type your feedback after the command!")
        .addField("What to do?" , "Type `=feedback` and add your feedback right after.")
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();

        const confirm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#993333")
        .setTitle("Confirm")
        .setDescription("Trolling results in not being able to do this command anymore.")
        .addField("Limit" , `Reactions will not be accepted after 10 minutes.`)
        .addField("Feedback" , `Your feedback will be shown as \n **${feedback}**`)
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp();

        if(!feedback) return message.reply(no_feedback);

        const confirmation = await message.channel.send(confirm);
        const emojis = ['✅', '❌'];

        emojis.forEach((emoji) => confirmation.react(emoji));

        const filter = (reaction, user) =>
  user.id === message.author.id && emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name);

const collector = confirmation.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 600000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  const [confirm, cancel] = emojis;

  confirmation.delete();

  if (reaction.emoji.name === cancel) {
    const cancelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#993333')
      .setTitle('Cancelled')
      .setDescription(
        `Cancelled! The feedback has not been sent.`,
      )
      .setFooter(message.author.username)
      .setTimestamp();
    return message.channel.send(cancelEmbed);
  }

  if (reaction.emoji.name === confirm) {
    const doneEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#993333')
      .setTitle('Sent')
      .setDescription(
        `Your feedback has been sent!`,
      )
      .setFooter(message.author.username)
      .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(doneEmbed);

    const feedback_admins = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#993333')
      .setTitle('Feedback')
      .setDescription(
        `Unread`,
      )
      .addFields(
          {name:"From" , value: message.author.username} ,
          {name:"In" , value: message.guild.name} ,
          {name:"Feedback" , value: feedback} ,
          {name:"❌" , value: "React to this message if the \n feedback isn't helpful"} ,
          )
      .setFooter(message.author.username)
      .setTimestamp();
    
        const feedback_channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("816714319172599828");
        const fbmsg = feedback_channel.send(feedback_admins)
        .then((embedMsg) => {
          const emojis2 = ['✅', '❌'];
          emojis2.forEach((emoji) => embedMsg.react(emoji))

        const filter2 = (reaction, user) =>
        !user.bot && emojis2.includes(reaction.emoji.name);

        const collector_2 = embedMsg.createReactionCollector(filter2, {max: 1});

        collector_2.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
          const [accept, deny] = emojis2;
          embedMsg.delete();
          if (reaction.emoji.name === accept) {
            const accepted = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('#009933')
           .setTitle('Feedback')
           .setDescription(
           `Accepted`,
            )
          .addFields(
          {name:"From" , value: message.author.username} ,
          {name:"In" , value: message.guild.name} ,
          {name:"Feedback" , value: feedback} ,
          )
          .setFooter(message.author.username)
          .setTimestamp();
          feedback_channel.send(accepted);
          }
      }
        )
        
    }
        )
}})}}
```

Comment: We will need more code. Where is `message` coming from? Can you update your question with it?

Comment: Your question has seemingly nothing to do with your error. Your error is saying that `message.guild` is undefined, which is probably because `message` isn't actually a `Message`. Could you show more of your code, such as where `message` is coming from?

Comment: I have posted my full code now

Comment: Great, one more thing... How do you call the `execute()` method in your main file?

Comment: I am using ```if(command === "feedback"){
        client.commands.get("feedback").execute(message, args);
    }```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `message.client.channels.fetch(channelID)` and since the method `fetch()` returns a Promise, you have to put an `await` in front of it and make your `execute` async.

So change this

```
execute: (message, args) => {
// your code
}
```

To this:

```
execute: async (message, args) => {
// example:
const channelID = '<Your target channel id>'
const channel = await message.client.channels.fetch(channelID)
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before, but I get an error anyways, which tells me await is only valid in an async function. If I put that code in an extra async function, it does not give me an error but the bot still doesn't send the message, now not even in the server the channel is in.

Comment: Try changing `async execute(message, args){ }` to `execute: async (message, args) =>{ }`

Comment: And is there a reason why you await here: `const confirmation = await message.channel.send(confirm);`?

Comment: When I do not await I get a error: confirmation.react is not a function